# Elementary proof that the Hilbert Matrix is invertible with integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deriving Inverse of Hilbert Matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix)

The inverse of the [Hilbert Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) is made up entirely of integer entries, but I can't seem to
find an elementary proof for that though, any hints?

Comment: The Wikipedia article gives an explicit, and not terribly complicated, expression for the entries of the inverse. Can't you just multiply the two matrices together to get a proof?

Comment: This came up before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at M.-D. Choi's paper

http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2975779.pdf

(American Math Monthly, 1983, "Tricks or Treats with the Hilbert Matrix") for this, and much more.

Comment: Freely avaliable online: http://vigo.ime.unicamp.br/HilbertMatrix.pdf

Comment: The solution provided in the paper uses the concept of the determinant, but this question is provided as an exercise problem in Hoffman and Kunze's book way before the determinant is introduced.
Before presenting the determinant solution, the above paper refers to the direct computation as "cumbersome".

Comment: Suffering is good for you:)

Answer (score 5):

Look at the paper below for what you are asking and much more! There is a lot known about the Hilbert matrix.

> *Tricks or Treats with the Hilbert Matrix* by Man-Duen Choi published at
>   The American Mathematical Monthly,
>   Vol. 90, No. 5 (May, 1983), pp.
>   301-312

Comment: Freely avaliable online: http://vigo.ime.unicamp.br/HilbertMatrix.pdf

Comment: In addition this two papers might be useful:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-01/S0002-9939-1958-0094626-0/S0002-9939-1958-0094626-0.pdf

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-04/S0002-9939-1958-0099599-2/S0002-9939-1958-0099599-2.pdf

