# Find the inverse of a matrix that is very similar to the Hilbert matrix

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-inverse

The standard Hilbert matrix $H$ is given by
$$H_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j-1},$$
and it has an inverse given for example [in this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix).

Now I have encountered a matrix $M$ of similar form, namely,

$$M_{ij}=\frac{1+(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j-1}.$$

Does anyone know the explicit formula for the inverse of M? Please provide some relevant reference if available.

A more general form for this question can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263216/find-the-inverse-of-a-more-general-matrix-that-is-similar-to-the-hilbert-matrix).

Comment: Note that $M$ splits into a direct sum of two square matrices: $A_{ij}:={1\over i+j-1/2}$ and $B_{ij}:={1\over i+j-3/2}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: It is a direct sum if you properly re-order the coordinate vectors: You need to take the basis $\left(e_1, e_3, e_5, \ldots, e_2, e_4, e_6, \ldots\right)$. Or, to say it in terms of matrices, you move all the columns with odd indices to the front, and all the columns with even indices to the back; then you do the same to the rows.

Comment: Dings: perhaps you should write a new MO question with your extended matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We present a generalization and also give an explicit solution.

If $M$ is the $n\times n$ matrix
$$M=\left[\frac{1+(-1)^{i+j}}{x_i-y_j}\right]_{i,j=1}^n$$
then the inverse matrix $K:=M^{-1}$ has entries given by
\begin{align}
K_{a,b}=\begin{cases}
2\frac{\prod_{2j-1\neq b}x_{2j-1}-y_a}{\prod_{2j-1\neq a}y_a-y_{2j-1}}\cdot \frac{\prod_{2k-1}x_b-y_{2k-1}}{\prod_{2k-1\neq b}x_{2k-1}-x_b} \qquad \text{$a, b$ are odd} \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 2\frac{\prod_{2j\neq b}x_{2j}-y_a}{\prod_{2j\neq a}y_a-y_{2j}}\cdot \frac{\prod_{2k}x_b-y_{2k}}{\prod_{2k\neq b}x_{2k}-x_b} \qquad \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{$a, b$ are even} \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \,\,\, 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
**Convention.** For instance, when $a$ is odd, the product $\prod_{2j-1\neq b}(x_{2j-1}-y_a)$ is understood as running through all odd integers from $1$ to $n$, excluding $b$.

The solution to your problem is found by replacing $x_i=i-1$ and $y_j=-j$. Hence, in this case,
\begin{align}
K_{i,j}=\begin{cases}\frac{2(-1)^{a+b}n_1^2}{16^{n_1-1}(2a+2b-3)}
\binom{2n_1+2a-2}{2a-2}\binom{2n_1+2b-2}{2b-2}\binom{2n_1-1}{n_1-a}\binom{2n_1-1}{n_1-b} \qquad i=2a-1,\, j=2b-1 \\
\qquad \frac{(-1)^{a+b}8ab}{16^n(2a+2b-1)}\binom{2n_2+2a}{2a}\binom{2n_2+2b}{2b}\binom{2n_2}{n_2-a}\binom{2n_2}{n_2-b} \qquad \qquad i=2a, \, j=2b \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \end{align}
where we use designating $n_1=\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$ and $n_2=\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor$.

Comment: sorry for nitpicking: Shouldn't the first one be $\prod_{2j-1\neq \color{red}a}(x_{2j-1}-y_a)$ and the one below that $\prod_{2j\neq \color{red}a}(x_{2j}-y_a)$? And why does the $\neq$ restriction only apply to one of the numerators, if the whole thing is symmetric? The factor $(x_b-y_b)$ is present but $(x_a-y_a)$ is not. (Edit: I see that $(x_a-y_a)$ is absent only after my suggested correction, so maybe yours is OK, it is only written in an asymmetric way)  But in any case, you want to add parenthesis.

Comment: I guess you mean "excluding $b$" at the end. I see now, the factor $(x_b-y_a)$ must not occur twice,that's all.

Comment: Or to write it symmetrically:
\begin{align}
K_{a,b}=\begin{cases}
2(x_b-y_a)\cdot \prod\limits_{2j-1\neq b}\dfrac{y_a-x_{2j-1}}{x_b-x_{2j-1}}\cdot \prod\limits_{2j-1\neq a}\dfrac{x_b-y_{2j-1}}{y_a-y_{2j-1}} \quad \text{$a, b$ are odd}\\
2(x_b-y_a)\cdot\quad \prod\limits_{2j\neq b}\dfrac{y_a-x_{2j}}{x_b-x_{2j}}\quad \cdot \prod\limits_{2j\neq a}\dfrac{x_b-y_{2j}}{y_a-y_{2j}} \qquad\text{$a, b$ are even}\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad \quad0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align} 
:)

Comment: With simulations, I find the $K_{i,j}$ provided by T. Amdeberhan is not consistent with its numerical inverse. When $a$, $b$ are odd, the result is $K_{i,j}/4$; when $a$,$b$ are even, it is $K_{i,j}*4*16^{n-n_1}$. Is that right?

Answer (score 15):

As observed in comments, the problem is equivalent to finding the inverse of the matrices $$H_\lambda:=\Big[{1\over i+j+\lambda}\Big]_{1\le i\le m\atop 1\le j\le m},$$ 
for $\lambda=-1/2$ and $\lambda=-3/2$ and order $m=\lceil n/2\rceil$, respectively $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. These are also particular cases of Cauchy matrices, whose inverses admit the explicit  Schetcher's formula  quoted in the linked question (see the wiki article on [Cauchy matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Cauchy_determinants) and the various answers in the linked question). As a matter of  fact, in this particular case the inversion formula takes quite a simpler form, and it turns out that the entries of $H_\lambda^{-1}$ are products of linear factors $\lambda+k$, with $2\le k\le 2m$ and multiplicity not larger than $2$. Precisely

$$H^{-1}_\lambda={1\over(m-1)!^2}\bigg[(-1)^{i+j}{m-1\choose i-1}{m-1\choose j-1}(\lambda+i+1)^{\overline m}(\lambda+j+1)^{\overline m}(\lambda+i+j)^{-1}\bigg]_{1\le i\le m\atop 1\le j\le m}$$ 
where $x^{\overline m}:=x(x+1)\dots(x+m-1)$ denotes a rising factorial.

Answer (score 3):

These matrices have been considered [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609283.pdf).